# Building a network graph off Zotero with Excel/Sheets

Tags: excel, networking, graph, google-sheets

I'm trying to build an authors network graph off of my Zotero bibliography. I've exported the database to .csv and need to edit it before using visualization software like Gephi, Cytoscape, etc.

So, I figure the data needs to be served as:

```
Column 1 -> Author X
Column 2 —> All authors who have worked with author X
```

This data would come from my current Authors column, which at the moment is formatted as:

```
Row1: Author X; Author Y; Author Z
Row2: Author A; Author B; Author C
Row3: Author X; Author Z; Author B
...
```

How can I process this data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Python-esque *pseudocode* for how you might go about transforming your current format to the desired format as specified.

```
srctbl  # source table
dsttbl  # destination table
for row in srctbl:
    authors = row.column("Authors").split("; ")
    for author in authors:
        if author not in dsttbl.column(1):
            dsttbl.column(1).addrow(author)
    for author in authors:
        peers = dsttbl.row(author).column(2).split("; ")
        for coauthor in authors:
            if coauthor is not author and coauthor not in peers:
                dsttbl.row(author).column(2).append(coauthor + "; ")
```